# How would i achieve this glow effect in eevee?

Tags: modeling, rendering

so my baby watches these sensory videos here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r2b2bvkjRcI

how would i go about achieving this glow effect in eevee?

Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: Hello, please make a screenshot so that we can see what effect you're talking about

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see 2 effects: Glare and bokeh, but the bokeh stays still. You can do both in the *Compositor*, but you can activate the *Bloom* effect in Eevee, which will give you the glare effect. As for the bokeh, create some grey bubble on a white background, like that:

[image]

Then in the *Compositor* mix the image with the rendered image through a *Mix Shader* in *Divide* mode:

[image]

Comment: Thankyou so much for your help!

Comment: How would i get just the edges to glow and keep the rest the same?

Comment: I think that Srinivasan Ramachandran gives a good solution for the glowing borders  ;)

Answer (score 2):

It is really easy. Apply emission shader with either a color or texture as the color input. Also enable the Bloom in the render properties for getting your desired effect

[image]

[image]

## [EDIT 1 - Emission along the edges]:

Simple again. Just assign a different material to the faces along the edges. For this to be done I did a loop cut on the faces of the cube along the edges and assigned them the emission material. For other faces that are not emitting they have the regular principled bsdf material

### Output you need

[image]

### Mesh editing necessary - cut along the edges to make them polygons/faces

[image]

### Add different material to non-emitting interior faces

[image]

Comment: Thankyou so much for your help! been working in cycles only since learning and this is my first time using evee

Comment: How would i get just the edges to glow and keep the rest the same?